# In git, how to rebase branch to master

Tags: git, branch, rename, rebase

I have new_branch and master.

Most of the good work have been done in new_branch.
And then someone made some mistake checking into master.

I now dont want to do merge new_branch to master because its just too messy.

Is there a way to force rebase the new_branch to become master.

Meaning, I want new_branch to become master, ignoring whatever is done in master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep master's history, you can make a new commit on master. The commit makes master have the same code with new_branch. This way, you don't need to force-push.

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin master
git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "foo" new_branch^{tree})
git push origin master
```

If you don't want to keep master's history, you can reset master to new_branch and force-push to overwrite master on the remote repository.

```
git checkout master
git reset new_branch --hard
git push origin -f master
```

Comment: actually, if I can keep master history would be good. but the merge will ask me to merge conflicts right ? (first solution). I dont want to merge conflict, I just want to forcefully overwrite with new_branch to the master

Comment: @Axil The 1st solution doesn't involve with `merge` and won't have any conflicts.

Comment: first solution will overwrite everything from new_branch to master ?

Comment: @Axil Yes. It creates a new commit on master. Then master will have the same code with new_branch.

Comment: when I pull master, I have this https://dpaste.org/dEWQ. Can I still follow the first solution ? or I have do certain clean ups ?

Comment: @Axil First update the local master, with `git checkout master;git fetch origin master;git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard`. And then follow the 1st solution. Replace `foo` with a detailed description which says why you make the commit.